# Is it possible to trigger a longer running background task with Next JS?

Tags: javascript, express, next.js

Next JS seems to automatically "clean up" API scripts using some logic after they are called (I'm assuming it's some period of time after the "res" is called back.  Is it possible to keep the script running for an indeterminate period of time after the res call back so that it would stay active until some longer running triggered background activity (like a slow render) is completed?

Simple example, an endpoint that could be "polled" to start a task while it's processing and will eventually respond with the completed result:

`api/myscript`

code:

```
var result = null
var processing = true

export default (req, res) => {
  if (result) {
    res.end(result)
  } else if (!processing) {
    new Promise((result, reject) => {
      exec(cmd, ("ffmpeg -takeareallylongtime", stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
      else {
        resolve("All done");
      }
    })})
    .then(_ => {
      result = "All done!"
    })
    .catch(_ => {
      result = "I'm sorry to have failed you."
    })
    res.end("Started task")
  } else {
    res.end("Still processing...")
  }
}
```

The behavior I'm seeing is that the runner kicks off, the client polls periodically and gets a valid status back, and at some point during the processing the page gets purged:

`[ event ] disposing inactive page(s)`

and the global values tracking result are cleared.

Comment: what do you mean by "API Scripts"?  Can you post an example script?  And are you referring to the development server or production server?

Comment: @brandon I'm referring to a component in the api directory (runs on server, similar to how express works).  I'll add an example.

Comment: And what is the behavior you are seeing with that api method?  Keep in mind SSR Caching is only for the dev server (unless you setup your own for production) and only applies to React pages.  Not to api calls.  That's just nodejs behavior.  I see nothing wrong with your script (other than you do not show any code that changes `processing` and you do not show what `someAsyncTask` function is.

Comment: @brandon The behavior I'm seeing is that at some point the script is getting reloaded and the longer running background task is cancelled without calling back. -- Perhaps it's just a dev environment issue?

Comment: you'd have to show `someAsyncTask`.  The only way a function would just stop running is if the nodejs process were being restarted (which may be happening I suppose).

Comment: That `someAsyncTask` should probably be run by something else, that  your server can trigger, so your server stays available. Remember that JS is single threaded, so any long running task you have you really want to fire off as a spawn/exec (with call arguments) so that you can immediately go back to "being a server" rather than "doing data processing and thread-blocking I/O"

Comment: In effect it is, in my case it's a `exec` of ffmpeg doing a long render server side...  So the next JS server is freed up quickly as the promise executes elsewhere.  I'd like my server to keep track of and queue tasks so it doesn't make sense to setup another pm2 and try to communicate between the two (one extra layer of complexity and fail points).  I'd like to just be able to tell next JS somehow that the page is still active even after I've res.end()...  If there isn't an easy way to do it with next JS I can probably hack some other async method together, but that's not the question really

Comment: Is it possible to keep global variables in /api server components on next js?  It seems the biggest problem is I'm losing my state when next "disposes" of my server js api components.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is in the api folder is a “function” script and is handled like AWS Lambda. These are typically meant to be short lived but due to the costs, Next.is would limit them. There’s also a chance that they run through API Gateway, which has max timeouts as well.

Comment: In my case I'm self hosted, rather than Next.is.  Though this answer may be relevant for those on that service :)

Comment: thanks for that hint. My page/api/ endpoints were only running for 28 seconds. Then closed without errors. Had my nextjs App deployed on AWS amplify.

Answer (score -1):

If your API calls are timingout then that actually means your Node/Express server is timing out your API requests. You can increase the default time out by using the following code

```
var server = app.listen();
server.setTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);
```

If they are very long-running tasks, then you can explore using WebSockets using socket.io or long polling techniques.

Comment: I think that is for the timeout period on calling result handler correct?  In this case, I want to return immediately, but keep processing my longer running "render" task.